# Hover area not changes, when changing droppable position

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I'm implementing folders-like UI, where user can drag and drop items between folders.

Folders are arranged top-down. When draggable item is over collapsed folder, it should be expanded to reveal its content. When folder in question is expanded, another folders below it will visually be pushed down with this animation.

**The problem**

Those folders, that are visually pushed down with expansion of folder in question, will still have hover areas in old positions.

Following [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6jjR2/1) illustrates the problem:

**HTML**:

```
<body>
<a class="item" href="#">Draggable Item</a>
<ul class="folders">
    <li>Folder 1&nbsp;<span>Drag and hold item over me.</span></li>
    <li>Folder 2&nbsp;<span>My hover area will not not change, because of pushing me down.</li>
</ul>
<div id="message"></div>
```

**JavaScript**:

```
$(".folders li").droppable({
    accept: ".item",
    hoverClass: "over",
    over: function (e, ui) {
        var folder = $(this);
        var isFirstFolder = $(".folders li").index(folder) === 0;
        if (isFirstFolder) setTimeout(function () {
            folder.animate({
                height: 100
            }, 600, function () {
                $("#message").html("Okay! Then drag a little bit lower");
            });
        }, 600);
    }
});
$(".item").draggable();
```

**CSS**:

```
.folders {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
}
.folders li {
    padding: 5px;
    border: solid thin black;
    margin: 3px;
}
.folders li span {
    color: #999;
    font-size: 13px;
}
.folders li.over {
    border: dashed thin black;
}
.item {
    background-color: #ccc;
    padding: 7px;
}
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is build in support for that: [jQueryUI docs refreshpositions](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-refreshPositions)

However :

> If set to true, all droppable positions are calculated on every
>   mousemove. *Caution: This solves issues on highly dynamic pages, but
>   dramatically decreases performance.*

So you could fix the position problem like that :

```
 $(".item").draggable({
        refreshPositions: true 
    });
```

Maybe we can look at what's going on behind the scene's when `refreshpositions` is set to true and make a "light version"  ?